# Check checkbox and set value on load content/page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cart

I have a some shop. In cart (when usually user is not logged) is checkbox for set Invoice. If is not checked - then user get a bill.

On next step, user has to login, and goes to Procced page. When user goes ahead (after login page), can't change checkbox without back to cart.

I need to check (after login, on procced page) Customer is Company or normal user (private) and if user is Company, set the invoice as default.

I have that code:
(I know is not pure php - is some kind of framework)

```
<!-- CART PAGE with checkbox -->
<div id="additionalRealizationInfo">
    ?{foreach system.cart.optionsData option}
        <label>
        <input class="additionalRealizationInfoCheckbox" 
                                       type="checkbox"  
                                       ?{if  true == option.option.enabled}
                                       checked="checked"
                                       ?{endif}
                                       name="additional?{=system.randomNumber}" 
                                       value="${system.controllerUrl}ToggleOption/?{=option.name}" />
                                       ?{=option.title}
        </label>
?{endforeach}


// The Value of checkbox is: toggleOption/facture






<!-- PROCCED PAGE without checkbox - On this page, after login, user see own choice from cart before login -->

<div id="additionalRealizationInfo">
    <h2>Infos</h2>
        <div>
        ?{foreach system.cart.optionsData option}
            <div>
            ?{if  true == option.option.enabled}
               You get Invoice
            ?{else}
                You get recive
            ?{endif}
        </div>
        ?{endforeach}
        </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var isCompany = "?{=system.userLogged.InvoiceData.company}"; <!-- Company Name -->
var enableInvoice = "?{=system.cart.invoiceEnabled}";

if (isCompany.lenght > 0) {
    $.get("${system.controllerUrl}setInvoiceEnabled",function(resp) {
        $.get("${system.baseUrl}view/enableinvoice",function(resp) {
            $("#additionalRealizationInfo").html(resp);
            });
     });
     $.get("${system.controllerUrl}toggleOption/facture",function(resp) {
      });
  }; 
</script>

// string to check choice: ?{if system.cart.invoiceEnabled}
```

// system.baseURL/view/enableinvoice is some code to show, that invoice is set default (when script works)

What's wrong. It doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, I'd examine this line of code:

```
if (isCompany.lenght > 0) {
```

You've misspelled length.  Try this:

```
if (isCompany.length > 0) {
```

OR, depending on if the value of the "isCompany" variable is true/false, you could write it as

```
if (isCompany) { // check boolean value instead
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I change the script and it works, but only after I reload/refresh a page.

```
     <!-- CART PAGE before and after login -->

        var companyCustomer = "?{=system.userLogged.InvoiceData.company}";
        //If user is logged, companyCustomer has a value. If not = ""

        var enableInvoice = "?{=system.cart.invoiceEnabled}"; 
// If true = "1" , If false = "". That's not a boolean string. 

        var klik = $("#additionalRealizationInfo>label:first-child>input:checkbox");

        if (companyCustomer) {
            klik.prop('checked',  true);
            klik.prop("disabled", true);
            klik.css('cursor','default');             
    $.get("${system.controllerUrl}toggleOption/facture",function(resp){
             console.log(resp);       
                    });
                }; // End if (companyCustomer)



    <!-- PROCEED PAGE after login -->
        var companyCustomer = "?{=system.userLogged.InvoiceData.company}";
        //If user is logged, companyCustomer has a value. If not = ""

        var enableInvoice = "?{=system.cart.invoiceEnabled}"; 
// If true = "1" , If false = "". That's not a boolean string. 

        if (companyCustomer) {
            if (enableInvoice) {
               } else {
            $.get("${system.controllerUrl}toggleOption/facture",function(resp){
                console.log(resp);
                    });
                }; // end if (enableInvoice)
              };  // end if (companyCustomer)
```

How it execute on load, and dynamically change/set this toggle option?
When I didn't check the checkbox in CART PAGE, go next to login, and automatically go to PROCEED PAGE I get

```
enableInvoice = "";
```

I tried `.ready` and `.load()` and `.live()` and nothing works. Tried execute by `.click` but I don't want this method. I don't want to also refresh page after content shows up.